# Serverless python requirements slim:true does nothing for dependency size

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

### Brief

when using the following settings in serverless.yml

```
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
    slim: true
    zip: true
```

`slim:true` and `slim:false` result in the same file size. What can I do to decrease the file size of the zip file?

### Full

I'm trying to get python code and it's dependencies onto an aws lambda function using the [serverless](https://www.serverless.com/) framework. following the recommendations provided [here](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-python-requirements) to reduce the dependency size to comply with the 250MB lambda limit. in my serverless.yml file I have the following:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requierments

custom:
  pythonRequierments:
    dockerizePip: true
    slim: true
    zip: true

functions:
...
```

my requierments.txt is the following:

```
xgboost==1.3.3
pandas==1.0.1
numpy == 1.18.5
...
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes..
```

which leads me to believe that my requierments.zip file is too large; the verbose output stated `uploading service test.zip file to s3 271.17 MB`.

I was playing around with making the file smaller, and I ran `sls deploy` with `dockerizePip`, and `slim` set to `false` for testing purpose, and I got the same result; a test.zip file of 271.17 Mb. This seemed perplexing, as I understood it `slim: true` would reduce the file size prior to zipping the file, but running with `slim:true` and `slim:false` resulted in the same file size. How can I make `slim` work?

### Update1:

I tried adding a `slimPattern` as discussed [here](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-python-requirements), within `pythonRequierments`

```
slimPatterns:
  - '**/*.dist-info/**'
```

but all dist info directories still exist in the zip file, and the output is the same size (271.17MB)

### Update 2:

I kept everything the same from update 1, but removed the .serverless directory and requierments.zip. All the .dist-info directories remain, even though I excluded them in `slimPatterns` (or so I thought).

### Update 3:

I tried using package exclude, doing the following:

```
package:
  exclude:
    -node_modules/**
    -'**/*.dist-info/**'
```

this did succeed in getting node_modules removed (which I should have done before), but did not succeed in changing `.requierments.zip` in any way. all `.dist-info` directories remain.

### Update 4:

I followed [this](https://dev.to/jolo/my-pain-with-serverless-and-aws-lambda-4hko), and added a `noDeploy` field in `pythonRequirements`, which included `setuptools` and `six`. despite this, both ended up in my `.requirements.zip`, and my file size hasn't changed (269.9 Mb, the same as update 3, which was slightly smaller due to the removal of `node_modules`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It didn't work for me either. I ended up using Layers using the following option -

```
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    slim: true
    layer: true
```

This reduced my deployment package size to less than 10mb. All the dependencies then go into a separate zip (~100mb) which creates a Lambda Layer. This helps reduce the Lambda cold-start problem as well.

Comment: For future readers, I too used this solution and it worked perfectly fine. I would prefer this option rather than going through the hassle of mounting an EFS volume (Depends on your use case though).

Comment: I recommend this solution for most use cases, including mine. You can read more about EFS vs layers vs other approaches [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/choosing-between-aws-lambda-data-storage-options-in-web-apps/). In some use cases, EFS may remain a better option

Comment: Solution did not work. The layer unzipped was over 250mb, so error came from layer zip instead of lambda zip.

Answer (score 1):

Really, the underlying concept behind this question is flawed. The main purpose for this question was how to squeeze large dependencies onto Lambdas size constraints. Recently, AWS released EFS support for Lambda functions, meaning you can mount volumes directly onto your lambda function. This means practically infinite storage, and no zipping requirements, meaning significantly less cold start. Also, one of these file systems can mount to multiple Lambda functions.

I won't go into insane detail, there's a lot to do, but If you want to get large dependency trees on Lambda, I recommend the following:

- create a VPC
- create an ec2 instance
- create an EFS volume and mount it to your ec2 instance
- install your dependencies to the efs instance via `pip install -r requierments.txt -t /mnt/.../efs/path`
- mount that EFS instance to your lambda in the serverless.yml
- add the modules on your EFS volume to your lambda function by appending it to path

Comment: comment a few years in the future: the point of lambda functions is to run small, atomic code elements. If you're deploying ML, just set up something like fargate or elastic beanstalk, and have it run a python docker container.